# Ember js active class not working for nested or sub-routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a link with route say `about` and couple of subroutes as `about.college` and `about.campus`.

Now I have `about` url in header top navigation bar and submenus in sidebar.

When I select any of menu from side bar the active class of `about` in main navigation bar is gets removed.

I want to make `about` link active when we are on `about.campus` or `about.college` route.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Code in the Header navbar**

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          {{#link-to "about.college"}}
            {{loc "About"}}
          {{/link-to}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Code in Sidbar**

```
<div class="content-area leftPanel_stats">
  <ul>
     <li>{{#link-to 'about.college'}}{{loc 'About College'}}{{/link-to}}</li>
     <li>{{#link-to 'about.campus'}}{{loc 'About Campus'}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Now when I am URL in `about.campus` I want header top button to be active

Comment: Works for me out of box. I have profile route and underneath it 8 (bookmarks, notifications etc) routes. The profile main route stays active.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold Which ember version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Ember : 2.4.5

Comment: Can you provide the source code of your navigation bar? There is no reason this shouldn't work, if you are using link-to helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the about in your header links to "about.college".

If it would link to just "about" route, it would remain active
because link-to helper adds active class based on what it routes to.

So what you could do is make about.index route (if you don't have one), and just have it redirect to "about.colege" in i.e model hook. Then you can have the link in your navbar be: 

     `{{#link-to "about"}}
         {{loc "About"}}
     {{/link-to}}`

Comment: yes you are right. I have 2 solutions now either use `currentWhen="about"`  for `link-to` component or paste the `about.college` tab code inside the `about.index`.

Comment: yeah, didn't know about current-when option, that seems like the best solution then.

Comment: Yes, I used `currentWhen` only. but your answer also solves problem so marked it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I used the `current-when` attribute to make the link active.

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          {{#link-to "about.college" current-when="about"}}
            {{loc "About"}}
          {{/link-to}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```